# "Call to a member function format() on a non-object" when converting date in PHP

Tags: php, date

I can not get rid of this error message:

> Call to a member function format() on a non-object

So, I go on googling and get some good source like [this StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2167916/convert-one-date-format-into-another-in-php).

I tried to do something similar, but I failed. This is my code :

```
$temp = new DateTime();
/*ERROR HERE*/ $data_umat['tanggal_lahir'] = $data_umat['tanggal_lahir']->format('Y-m-d');
$data_umat['tanggal_lahir'] = $temp;
```

So, i did trial & errors, and I found out if I do this:

```
$data_umat['tanggal_lahir'] = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
```

The date will successfully converted, BUT it always return today's date (which i dont want).

I want to convert the date so that `10/22/2013` will be `2013-10-22`.

Comment: should be `$temp->format('Y-m-d');` not `$data_umat['tanggal_lahir']->format('Y-m-d');`

Comment: use `strtotime()` function.

Comment: @bansi i tried $temp = new DateTime();
   $data_umat['tanggal_lahir'] = $temp->format('Y-m-d'); but it returns todays time. Thanks :D

Comment: `new DateTime()` always returns current date time unless you specify some other value like `new DateTime('2010-10-12')`. check @Glavić's solution

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You are calling method `format()` on non-object. Try this:

```
$data_umat['tanggal_lahir'] = new DateTime('10/22/2013');
$data_umat['tanggal_lahir'] = $data_umat['tanggal_lahir']->format('Y-m-d');
```

or one-liner:

```
$data_umat['tanggal_lahir'] = date_create('10/22/2013')->format('Y-m-d');
```

Comment: +1 for the 1 liner. I prefer to use the `Y-m-d` format though.

Comment: @bansi: This one-liner is kinda funny to me, because first part (`date_create`) is procedural style, and second one (`->format()`) is object oriented style. Perfect example of object oriented style one-liner would be `(new DateTime('10/22/2013'))->format('Y-m-d')`, but that is for PHP >= 5.4.0, since the example in answer is for PHP >= 5.2.0.

Comment: @bansi: OP said he has input format `10/22/2013` that he needs to change to `Y-m-d`. `10/22/2013` is valid/supported [input format](http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.formats.php) of date (american format = m/d/Y).

Answer (score 3):

You can use strtotime() to convert this.  Its converts the given date to a timestamp and then by using date() function you can convert the timestamp to desired date format.

Try this..

```
$date = '10/22/2013';
$timestamp = strtotime($date);
$new_date = date('Y-m-d',$timestamp );
```

Answer (score 1):

`$data_umat['tanggal_lahir']` is not an instance of `DateTime`, however `$temp` is.

Is `$data_umat['tanggal_lahir']` meant to be be an instance of `DateTime`

Answer (score 1):

`$data_umat['tanggal_lahir']` is not an instanceof of object `DateTime`

use to make it instance of `DateTime`

```
$data_umat['tanggal_lahir'] = new DateTime();
```

Answer (score 1):

`$temp = new \DateTime(); (need \ ) 
/*ERROR HERE*/ $data_umat['tanggal_lahir'] = $data_umat['tanggal_lahir']->format('Y-m-d');
$data_umat['tanggal_lahir'] = $temp;`

Answer (score 1):

when using Symfony or Slim with Doctrine, try this:

//form[birthday = "2000-12-08"]

[...]

```
$birthday = \DateTime::createFromFormat("Y-m-d",$formData['birthday']);

$obejct = new $object();
$object->setBirthday($birthday);
```

[...]

Answer (score -2):

If you encounter this issue when using Symfony, try this hack:

Open:Your Symfony Root/vendor/doctrine/dbal/lib/Doctrine/DBAL/Types/DateTimeType.php

Go to line 50 something where the function `convertToDatabaseValue()` is declared.

The original code:

```
return ($value !== null)
        ? $value->format($platform->getDateTimeFormatString()) : null;
```

Change to:

```
 return ($value !== null)
            ? $value : null;
```

Seems Symfony is doing an extra conversion when passing a string as the datestring.

Directly passing a DateTime ojbect won't work as it will prompt another error saying "Object DateTime can't be converted to string".

Comment: Never do something like this please O_O.