# Array of datetime to mysql datetime format

Tags: php, mysql, datetime

I have an array called `$process_date` with two elements. The elements are in this format `dd/mm/yy H:i:s`

```
$process_date = array(
  "27/10/15 17:00:00",
  " 27/10/15 18:00:00"
)
```

I need to convert it to mysql datetime format to query a field in my database. I tried

```
$myDateTime = \DateTime::createFromFormat('d-m-Y H:i:s', $process_date[0]);
$newDateString = $myDateTime->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
```

And I get

```
Call to a member function format() on a non-object
```

I found this link ["Call to a member function format() on a non-object" when converting date in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19220143/call-to-a-member-function-format-on-a-non-object-when-converting-date-in-php)
and tried

```
$myDateTime = new \DateTime($process_date[0]);
$myDateTime->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
```

I get

```
DateTime::__construct(): Failed to parse time string (27/10/15 17:00:00) at position 0 (2): Unexpected character
```

Am I missing something?

Thanks in advance

Comment: I believe you need to replace the `/` in your process_date array with a `-` so that the dates are as such `27-10-15 17:00:00`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> The elements are in this format dd/mm/yy H:i:s

You have `d/m/y` values, and try to extract with the format `d-m-y`.
Use this instead :

```
$myDateTime = \DateTime::createFromFormat('d/m/y H:i:s', $process_date[0]);
```

Comment: you missed something. His format should actually be `'d/m/y H:i:s'` since he has the two digit years.

Comment: Thanks it worked `\DateTime::createFromFormat('d/m/y H:i:s', $process_date[0]);`

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
$dateArray = array(
    '27/10/15 17:00:00',
    '27/10/15 18:00:00',
);

$formattedDateArray = array();

foreach ($dateArray as $date) {
    $myDateTime = \DateTime::createFromFormat('d/m/y H:i:s', $date);
    $formattedDateArray[] = $myDateTime->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
}
```

Note the lowercase "y" for year, as the year format is 2 decimals only. "Y" will output the year as "0015", whereas "y" will output as "2015".